# cv2.fillConvexpoly equivalent in OpenCV 2.0

Tags: image-processing, opencv, python

I was trying to mask a region of interest defined by a polygon from an image. There is a module in the latest OpenCV versions called as `cv2.fillConvexpoly` for this purpose. Is there an equivalent of this  in older version of OpenCV (version 2.0)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The oldest release of OpenCV currently available at [opencv.org](http://opencv.org/releases.html) is 2.3.0 from 2011-07-04, and the 2.3 docs have `cv2.fillConvexPoly` (see [here](http://docs.opencv.org/2.3/modules/core/doc/drawing_functions.html#fillconvexpoly)).  Note that capitalization of the function name is slightly different from the one in your question.